# What generic type argument to use for TaskCompletionSource if no result is actually needed

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

If we want to create a `TaskCompletionSource<T>` based `Task` that has no `Result` we still need to provide a `T` and set a dummy value. Like this:

```
Task SomethingAsync() {
 var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<?>();
 tcs.SetResult(default(?)); //Can happen later as well, this is for demo purposes.
 return tcs.Task;
}
```

What's the best type to use for `T` from a performance standpoint?

It seems hard to answer that question purely from running a micro benchmark. I imagine the answer depends on the rest of the application. For example, if we use `TaskCompletionSource<bool>` that will cause the JIT to generate specialized code and cause memory usage. But it will not add memory usage if the app already uses boolean based tasks. If we use `TaskCompletionSource<object>` we might use more memory for each task (or not depending on the runtime).

That's why I think a benchmark alone cannot answer the question and it must be answered by reasoning as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want the best possible solution, you need to declare an empty struct. This way, the system won't have to reserve any space for the payload. This is actually what is done in the base class library:

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Threading/Tasks/TaskExtensions.cs,6e36a68760fb02e6,references

```
private struct VoidResult { }
```

From there, you can use `TaskCompletionSource<VoidResult>`, and `TrySetResult(default(VoidResult))` to mark the task as completed.

That said, it saves a tiny bit of memory, but I don't think it has any impact on execution time (even at nanoseconds level). Whether you use a `TaskCompletionSource<byte>` (one byte reserved for the payload) or `TaskCompletionSource<object>` (four bytes reserved for the payload), a 32 bit CPU is still able to do the assignment in a single operation.

Comment: Good idea. I wonder whether byte, bool and VoidResult save any bytes at all due to the way object layout is done. Objects are 8 byte aligned on 64 bit (I think). Also, this forces a new set of jitted code for each assembly that does this.

Comment: @boot4life Hard to answer. `TaskCompletionSource<T>` has a single field (storing a `Task<T>`), and fills 4 bytes of RAM on x86. Any additional payload would push the reserved space to the next 4 bytes alignment. But I don't really know how 0 bytes struct like `VoidResult` are handled. If done correctly (it probably is), then it means that the system can store the `TaskCompletionSource<VoidResult>` in a single 4 bytes space (not counting the CLR-specific headers) whereas `TaskCompletionSource<byte>` and `TaskCompletionSource<object>` would use 8 bytes (because of alignment)

Comment: The TaskCompletionSource would not be affected in any case but the Task<T> size would be. In 4.6 I see a single `T result` field in the derived class. So ideally the derived portion would end up layouted empty.

Comment: @boot4life Oh, that's true. I don't know why I was working on the assumption that a `T` payload was stored in the `TaskCompletionSource<T>`